# One more fight between Unicode, Python 3 and programmer. Decoding string

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

The problem is to convert the bytes to unicode, when that bytes already saved in string. Here is an example:

```
s1 = '\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0'
s2 = b'\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb1'

print(s1)  #  Here is the problem: prints a trash (Ð°Ð±)
print(s2.decode('utf-8'))  #  Everything is OK, printing 'ба' (two cyrillic symbols)
```

But how can i decode the data from **s1** now? I can't add **b''** modifier before the **s1** declaration cause **s1** may come from internet, so i can't just declare **s1** like i declared **s2**.
I found that **b''** modifier works like a **bytes()** function, but when i tried to call it:

```
s3 = bytes(s1, 'utf-8')
```

There was a trash again:

```
print(s3.decode('utf-8'))  #  Ð°Ð±
```

**So the question is:** what should i do with **s1** that it becomes the 'ба' in terminal output?

I googled a lot but all that i found was not that i need.

That is what i need:

```
s4 = SOME_WONDERFUL_MAGIC(s1)
print(s4)  #  Prints 'ба'
```

Very thanks for everybody who can help and sorry me please for bad english.

**UPDATE:** Oops, the problem returned. I hoped that 1st answer will help me, but i found that:

```
s1 == '\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0'  #  BUT
s1 != '\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0'
```

What do i mean:
I used the 'requests' package to make a POST request to Flask server. It responses me:

```
req = requests.post(hostName)
print(req.text)  #  b'testText'
#  BUT!
print(req.text[2:-1]  #  testText
```

It means that bytes representation of testText represented as string like that:

```
s5 = "b'tumba'"
```

So the real question is: how to extract **tumba** from **"b'tumba'"** (if tumba may contain cyrillic symbols)?

Comment: How can a unicode object "come from the internet"? If it's from the internet it's bytes. It's being decoded to unicode _somewhere_, the question is where?

Comment: @gnibbler: It's possible that "come from the internet" may mean "come from one of the internet-related modules in the stdlib or elsewhere, which decoded it behind my back". In that case, of course, the OP has to tell us which module he used, and we can tell him how to set an encoding explicitly instead of defaulting to something incorrect, which will solve the problem without needing any wonderful magic.

Comment: @abarnert, that's exactly what I was trying say

Comment: @gnibbler: Yes, and your point is crucial; I just wasn't sure a novice would understand it. Novices are usually not directly processing data off `sock.read()`, and may not realize that `requests` or `ElementTree` or whatever is doing some magic with a default value or guess.

Comment: For everybody who asked for source of unicode object: it is coming as a response from Flask server. 'requests' package is using for making requests. But there is no more problem: gnibbler answered a question, very gratz.

Answer (score 4):

`s1` is probably being incorrectly decoded as [ISO-8859-1(latin1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) somewhere.

You can try reencoding

```
>>> s4 = s1.encode('ISO-8859-1')
>>> s4.decode('UTF-8')
'ба'
```

You real bug is finding where the decoding is happening though.

Stop treating unicode and bytes interchangeably and the fighting will stop :)

Comment: I worked for test string, but real life surprised me with new problem (question is updated).

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution that worked for me:

```
s1 = '\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0'
s4 = bytes(s1, encoding='latin1').decode('utf-8')
print(s4)
```

Comment: Sure, but if you've got data that "comes from the internet" and is being incorrectly decoded as Latin-1 this time, so you write code that re-encodes it just to decode it properly, it's all going to fail with the next piece of data that gets incorrectly decoded as something else. Without finding out _how_ it got incorrectly decoded, you can't fix the problem.

Comment: If you don't know what you have (encoding), then it's quite hard to guess encoding and even if you do this, there's always a possibility of failure. So, I just assumed it's a UTF-8.

Comment: You're missing the point. We can assume the actual bytes are UTF-8 because the OP said so. What we can't assume is that the bytes are getting improperly decoded with Latin-1, as opposed to, say, with `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (which would make your code break on other machines), or [`Unicode, Dammit`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) (which would make it break with different data), etc.